# Delete local SVN authentication credentials with SharpSVN

Tags: c#, svn, authentication, sharpsvn

I’m using SharpSVN.

I have to delete the SVN authentication credentials stored in the PC.

I try with

```
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    // Clear predefined handlers and previous authentication
    client.Authentication.Clear();
}
```

it delete credential for the during of program, but it *doesn't delete the credentials data stored in the computer*.

Someone now how to do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I have found is:

```
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())

{

    //delete all Svn Authentication credential stored in the computer    
    foreach (var svnAuthenticationCacheItem in client.Authentication.GetCachedItems(SvnAuthenticationCacheType.UserNamePassword))    
    {   
        svnAuthenticationCacheItem.Delete();    
    }

}
```

This solution **delete all SVN credentials** data stored.

The svnAuthenticationCacheItem has a lot of information about credential stored in computer.

I found idea for the solution here:
http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=728&viewType=browseAll&dsMessageId=319851

I hope this could help someone